# How to solve this type of KeyError?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to write a program for scraping images to create datasets to use for neural networks, however I'm getting a few problems

here's the code:

```
from imutils import paths
import argparse
import requests
import cv2
import os

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-u", "--C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt", 
                required=False, help="path containing URLs")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--C:/Users/artus/datasets/ShoesImage", 
                required=False, help="folder for downloaded images")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# grab the list of URLs from the input file, then initialize the
# total number of images downloaded thus far
rows = open(args["urls"]).read().strip().split("\n")
total = 0
```

when executed it should download all the images from the urls specified in the urls.txt file, however I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/artus/untitled5/imagescraping.py", line 16, in <module>
    rows = open(args["urls"]).read().strip().split("\n")
KeyError: 'urls'
```

Comment: This particular problem has nothing to do with web-scraping or downloading images — it's related only to your use of `argparse.ArgumentParser`.

Comment: It's a good idea to `print(args)` right after `parse_args()` so you have a clear idea of what the parser has done.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of add_argument is the "long name" for the argument. For the first argument, you'll be passing `--urls`, and then argparse will make the value the user passes available as `args["urls"]`:

```
# ...
ap.add_argument("-u", "--urls", type=str,
                required=False, help="path containing URLs")
```

Then, at the command line, pass in the argument:

```
python imagescraping.py --urls C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt
```

Also, I don't think you need to wrap it in `vars`.

Comment: the code now works but I don't know why I'm getting the namespace error now, which is the reason why I was trying to do the vars, but doesn't seem to work. Do you know any other way I could treat the object as a dictionary and then use the urls to download the images?

Answer (score 0):

When I copy-n-paste your argparse code to a script:

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-u", "--C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt", 
                required=False, help="path containing URLs")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--C:/Users/artus/datasets/ShoesImage", 
                required=False, help="folder for downloaded images")
args = ap.parse_args()
print(args)
```

and call it without arguments:

```
0923:~/mypy$ python3 stack56745387.py 
Namespace(**{'C:/Users/artus/datasets/ShoesImage': None, 'C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt': None})
```

and asking for help:

```
1743:~/mypy$ python3 stack56745387.py -h
usage: stack56745387.py [-h] [-u C:/USERS/ARTUS/DATASETS/URLS.TXT]
                        [-o C:/USERS/ARTUS/DATASETS/SHOESIMAGE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -u C:/USERS/ARTUS/DATASETS/URLS.TXT, --C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt C:/USERS/ARTUS/DATASETS/URLS.TXT
                        path containing URLs
  -o C:/USERS/ARTUS/DATASETS/SHOESIMAGE, --C:/Users/artus/datasets/ShoesImage C:/USERS/ARTUS/DATASETS/SHOESIMAGE
                        folder for downloaded images
```

You probably intended the "--C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt" to be something like the default value, but you defined it as the long flag and `dest` for the argument.  (Nothing in your setup specified `urls` as the desired `dest` or key.)

which you'd have to use as:

```
1750:~/mypy$ python3 stack56745387.py --C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt foobar
Namespace(**{'C:/Users/artus/datasets/ShoesImage': None, 'C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt': 'foobar'})
```

Changing the code to:

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-u", "--urls", default="C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt", 
                required=False, help="path containing URLs (default: %(default)s)")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--images",default="C:/Users/artus/datasets/ShoesImage", 
                required=False, help="folder for downloaded images (default: %(default)s)")
args = ap.parse_args()
print(args)

1802:~/mypy$ python3 stack56745387.py -h
usage: stack56745387.py [-h] [-u URLS] [-o IMAGES]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -u URLS, --urls URLS  path containing URLs (default:
                        C:/Users/artus/datasets/urls.txt)
  -o IMAGES, --images IMAGES
                        folder for downloaded images (default:
                        C:/Users/artus/datasets/ShoesImage)
1803:~/mypy$ python3 stack56745387.py --urls foobar
Namespace(images='C:/Users/artus/datasets/ShoesImage', urls='foobar')
```

Now you could use `args.urls` or `vars(args)['urls']`.

Comment: As I said for the other answer, the code works but I'm getting the namespace error as args is an object and not a dictionary. any way I can solve it?

Comment: I showed you two ways of getting the value of the 'urls' attribute from the `args` produced by `parse_args`.